# NPM Cordova Install - generator-karma does not satisy

Tags: node.js, cordova

I'm attempting to install cordova on my windows 8 machine but continue to have issues. When I run **npm install -g cordova** I get the following error:

*The package generator-karma does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements*

I have nodejs installed correctly and configured in my PATH variable. I have also tried adding various karma dependencies to my package.json file in C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm

I can also confirm Java and Ant are installed and added to the PATH variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added that to the package.json was the last step "generator-karma": "~",